# Find smallest positive integer solution of $x$ for $a^x \leq b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$a \in \Bbb R, 0 < a < 1.$
$b \in \Bbb R, 0 < b < 1.$
$x \in \Bbb N.$

Let $a^x \leq b$

How can I find smallest positive integer solution of $x$ for given $a$ and $b$?

[Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+0.9%5Ex+%3C%3D0.01+over+the+natural+numbers) can solve this.

Comment: Do you know anything about logs? As in logarithms, not what get from cutting trees.

Comment: @Lost1 I didn't know logarithm can solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equality holds if $x=\log_a(b)=\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}$. When $x$ gets larger, $a^x$ becomes smaller, so you want the smallest integer larger than that:
$$
x=\left\lceil\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}\right\rceil
$$